# Short way to create simple multiple rows in a tabular

Tags: tables

Let me please emphasise first, that I do not need a sophisticated tabular --- I'm looking for a clever way to create a simple, but long tabular.

I'd like to create an empty tabular which has e.g. 25 rows. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tabular}{|*{4}{c|}}\hline
   \textbf{Akten-Nr.} & \textbf{Angelegenheit} & \textbf{Frist} & \textbf{SB} \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
      & & & \\\hline
       & & & \\\hline
       & & & \\\hline

  \end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

What I'd like to write is something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tabular}{|*{5}{c|}}\hline
   \textbf{Akten-Nr.} & \textbf{Angelegenheit} & \textbf{Frist} & \textbf{SB} \\\hline
    \multiplerows{25}{& & & \\\hline}

  \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

You see, I'd like to save the effort to print 25 (or howmuch ever) times  `& & & \\\hline` and instead one line with a »multiplicator«.

Any ideas of a (simple?) package, which offers something like »**\multiplerows{}{}**«? Or can someone with greater karma in tabulars spill some lines of code?

Comment: Will you need to fill this table later?

Comment: @LudovicC. No, probably not. But out of couriousity: why?

Comment: Just to know if David Carlisle's solution is ok or if you need something different. BTW, it is quite "easy" to insert 20 or 100 times the same pattern using some text editors and then you can fill the table if needed.

Comment: @LudovicC. Yes, I'm using Emacs and `M-x replace-string` is a basic there. Thanks! David's solution is all I need.

Comment: I was more thinking to `C-a C-k C-x ( C-y C-j C-x ) C-u 24 C-x e`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\def\rows#1{%
\ifnum#1>0
 & & & \\\hline
\expandafter\rows\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1-1\relax}%
\fi}
\begin{document}

  \begin{tabular}{|*{4}{c|}}\hline
   \textbf{Akten-Nr.} & \textbf{Angelegenheit} & \textbf{Frist} & \textbf{SB} \\\hline
\rows{25}
  \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. In LaTeX that would be: `\newcommand{\multiplerows}[2]{
\ifnum#1>0
#2
\expandafter\rows\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1-1\relax}%
\fi
}
` (If not, please give a hint.)

Comment: @KeksDose yes looks about right where #2 is &&&&\\\hline in this case